# How can I simplify this function into a function that checks all error codes from a list?

Tags: python, loops

My problem is that I have a many functions that essentially do the same thing depending on a given error code. How can I develop a loop to simplify these functions into one algorithm that checks the error code from a list or table of error codes. As well as detecting the error code string, I would like to count occurrences for each unique error code.

I've tried to make a table that includes column such as error and description. I am confused how I can match the error with the description

```
file_path = ('/Users/.../error.txt')


def check_error1():

    count = 0
    fault = ':error1'

    with open(file_path) as f:
        for line in f.readlines():
            if fault in line:
                count += fault.count(fault)
    return count != 0

if check_error1():
    print 'error 1 occurred ' , count, ' times || WARNING, Bot failed to read data'

print 'error 1 occurred ' , count, ' times || WARNING, Bot failed to read data'
```

Comment: Use collections.Counter

Answer (score 1):

You could find all faulty lines in the file and then take the `len`gth of that:

```py
def check_error1():
    with open(file_path) as f:
        return len(line for line in f if ':error1' in line)
```